# Android app compatibility issue on Nook HD+ and Asus TF300T

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play, android-market-filtering

I have a weird App compatibility issue.
As per the Developer console, my app seems to be compatible and available on the Nook HD+ and Asus TF300T. It shows a "Green" checkmark against these two.

However, two users have gotten back saying that the Play Store shows my app as incompatible with their device.

This is what I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="true" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

<application android:name="{application_class}"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity...
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: It will be good if you provide all code from manifest?

Comment: edited original post, thx

Comment: Had look at [Filters on Google Play](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html)?

Comment: Yes indeed. The app works on many Tablets including my Nexus7 via the Play Store. Guess I ll have to try some trial and error and publish a alpha/beta version to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I figured out the reason:

```
aapt dump badging <myapk>
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large'
```

I was surprised that xlarge is missing from the above supports-screens.
And of course, Nook HD+ and Asus TF300T are >9in devices! So this may be the reason.

Now I have explicitly added the following in my manifest and aapt shows `xlarge`:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
 android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

`xlargeScreens` was introduced in API 9 and MAYBE this is why `xlarge` was false by default?
Weirdly, the dev console shows it as supported.

Now off to test it against the user's device.

Answer (score 0):

Ever get this to work?  Just a thought, can you use the permission "READ_PHONE_STATE" on a Nook?

Comment: Yes, had to explicitly set xlarge = true in the manifest. Permission would be ignored if not applicable.